# MongoDB and Meteor find time conflict

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor Application that initializes a MongoDB with some data, that is used further on in the application. The problem is when it is already inserted I do not want to insert it again, so I tought of adding this check:

```
Meteor.startup(()=>{
    if (CodesData.find().count() === 0) {
       /*insert codes */
    }   

});
```

However the database seems empty, but when I start the application every record is doubled (even more after a few times). This code is added in my collection, maybe that is wrong?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please add the info, whether this is server or client  code and post the complete function code. Collection.find().count() is a standard mongo driver feature and works flawlessly in Meteor so the source of the issue is likely to be somewhere else.

Comment: Where would you put that Meteor.startup code block, I putted it in the same file as where I define my Collection and the Collectionscheme.

Comment: Try to put it in a separate file that is only included on the server. If you import the file on client and server the startup code will run on both

Comment: So now it only runs when i start the server, not restart?

Comment: It runs every time you restart but now it does not run a second time on the client, too. If there is still the mismatch between the docs of the collection and the count() value, please post more code or best - create a minimal example that can be reproduced with a newly created application.

Comment: It seems to work now. If I find issues, I will post more code, thanks for your help.